# Why isn't std::hash specialized for containers?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-set

I started looking into `std::unordered_set` today and quickly found that `std::hash` doesn't specialize for all types -- only for those types that are [listed here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/hash/), but I couldn't find the reasoning for why this is the case. Coming from a more pythonic background, it seems like such a hassle to force people to write their own hash function when all you want is a set of tuples.

So, why doesn't `std::hash` try to specialize for all built in types, or if not for *all* built in types, at least for the most popular containers: `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, &c. <strike>Couldn't the implementation at the very least just do something with the memory address of whatever you're trying to hash ?</strike>

Comment: `pair` and `tuple` are not containers. They're also not particularly "popular". "*Couldn't the implementation at the very least just do something with the memory address of whatever you're trying to hash ?*" No. C++ isn't Python.

Comment: combining hashes is no simple task, so they probably left it like that on purpose so that you would explicitly have to decide how they container gets hashed.

Comment: If two objects compare equal, then for just about any reasonable application their hash needs to compare equal as well. This forbids using an object's address as part of its hash, otherwise objects would only ever have equal hashes if they happened to randomly collide.

Comment: this reference is more accurate: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash. In particular, the specializations you are looking for: "...they exist, but cannot be used. " (though I might be splitting hairs ;)

Comment: Though I can't find a source attesting to this, I believe the problem was that different approaches to hashing containers have _very_ different performance/quality/security tradeoffs, and the standards committee didn't want to enshrine one as The Way to hash them.

Comment: I think they are just not implemented yet and might very well be implemented later. See this note: *"Note: additional specializations for std::pair and the standard container types, as well as utility functions to compose hashes are available in boost::hash."* taken from this link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: @Ari: Note that this uses `boost::hash`, not `std::hash`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Right, I mentioned that since historically some parts of the Standard C++ Library are predated in boost.

Comment: *Couldn't the implementation at the very least just do something with the memory address of whatever you're trying to hash ?* -- You're not the first one to believe that using addresses as keys is the "solution" that should have been implemented.  Addresses are not global unique identifiers.  Using addresses as keys in any container is dangerous, as addresses can be invalidated, reused later for a different object, etc.  The standards committee isn't going to get involved in that mess.

Comment: `std::hash` actually does produce a hash value of the pointer at least for this type: *"There is no specialization for C strings. std::hash<const char*> produces a hash of the value of the pointer (the memory address), it does not examine the contents of any character array."* from here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: @Ari I would argue that there is enough of a distinction between a C-string and a string literal (`const char*`) that negates the point.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True, but it should only apply to actual **container** types, where `pair` and `tuple` store objects directly.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I'm not sure I understood what your comment is saying. If you mean that my earlier comment about equality only applies to containers, then that is incorrect. If a `pair` or `tuple` compares to equal to another `pair` or `tuple then their hash should also compare equal.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry, I thought you were commenting on *Why isn't std::hash specialized for containers?*, which I agree that they should not be specialized since the data are stored as pointer/references, which I think `tuple` and `pair` should/can be specialized since they store data directly. But now I realized you were commenting on OP's last question on why not implement it based on their memory addresses.